# Add (sum) variable to existing value in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database with column `"kredit"`. I want to add `$dobitak` to `kredit`.

So if is in database `kredit=10`, and `$dobitak=15 kredit+dobitak=25` but my code return me `kredit=15` in database.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user
    SET  kredit='kredit' + '".$dobitak."'
    WHERE id='" . $info['user_id'] . "'";
```

What I need to change to get correct result in database?

Comment: Use back ticks or remove the single quotes,you are adding a string.

Comment: Remove single quotes arround the column  `SET  kredit=kredit + '".$dobitak."'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this ...

```
$sql = "UPDATE user
    SET  kredit=kredit + ".$dobitak."
    WHERE id='" . $info['user_id'] . "'";
```

Because for integer type field you need not enclose with "'"

Comment: If you want appreciate then choose this as correct answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
kredit = kredit + '". $dobitak ."'
WHERE id='" . $info['user_id'] . "'";
```

Remove the ' ' from around kredit